# Unable to delete Node in Binary Tree which have two children in CPP. I've pasted the code below and highlighted out the error part

Tags: c++, binary-tree

I've pasted my whole code below.

I'm able to delete node successfully with no child or one child but unable to delete node with two children.

In node with two children I'm using approach where I swap the value of targeted node with it's leaf child and then trying to delete the leaf node.
But while deleting it's giving error **exited with code=3221225725 in 0.474 seconds** I also tried creating other functions to delete it but end up getting the same.

I've tried removing delete and the code is running just fine and the value is swapped successfully too! I've also used same approach for Binary Search Tree and it was working just fine!

```
#include <iostream>

class BinaryTree
{
  struct Node
{
    int data;
    Node *left_child;
    Node *right_child;
};

Node *root;

Node *appendage(Node *root, int data)
{
    if (root == NULL)
    {
        root = new Node();
        root->data = data;
        root->left_child = NULL;
        root->right_child = NULL;
        return root;
    }

    else if (root->left_child == NULL and root->right_child == NULL)
    {
        root->left_child = appendage(root->left_child, data);
    }

    else if (root->left_child != NULL and root->right_child == NULL)
    {
        root->right_child = appendage(root->right_child, data);
    }

    else
    {
        root->left_child = appendage(root->left_child, data);
    }

    return root;
}

Node *deletion(Node *root, int data)
{
    if (root == NULL)
    {
        return root;
    }

    else if (data != root->data)
    {
        root->left_child = deletion(root->left_child, data);
        root->right_child = deletion(root->right_child, data);
    }

    else
    {
        if (root->left_child == NULL && root->right_child == NULL)
        {
            delete root;
            return NULL;
        }

        else if (root->left_child == NULL)
        {
            Node *temp_node = root;
            root = root->right_child;
            delete temp_node;
        }

        else if (root->right_child == NULL)
        {
            Node *temp_node = root;
            root = root->left_child;
            delete temp_node;
         }
        //////// ***ERROR BELOW (DUE TO DELETE)***

        else //DELETE WITH TWO NODES
        {
            Node *temp_node = last_right_node(root);
            root->data = temp_node->data;
            delete temp_node;
        }

        //////// ***ERROR ABOVE  (DUE TO DELETE)***


    }        
    return root;
}

void inorder_display(Node *root)
{
    if (root == NULL)
    {
        return;
    }
    inorder_display(root->left_child);
    std::cout<<root->data<<" ";
    inorder_display(root->right_child);
}

void preorder_display(Node *root)
{
    if (root == NULL)
    {
        return;
    }
    std::cout<<root->data<<" ";
    preorder_display(root->left_child);
    preorder_display(root->right_child);
}

void postorder_display(Node *root)
{
    if (root == NULL)
    {
        return;
    }
    postorder_display(root->left_child);
    postorder_display(root->right_child);
    std::cout<<root->data<<" ";
}

Node *destroy_tree(Node *root)
{
    if (root != NULL)
    {
        destroy_tree(root->left_child);
        destroy_tree(root->right_child);
        delete root;
    }
    return root;
}

Node *last_right_node(Node *root)
{
    if (root == NULL)
    {
        return root;
    }

    else if (root->right_child == NULL)
    {
        return root;
    }

    else
    {
        return last_right_node(root->right_child);
    }
};

public:

BinaryTree()
{
    root = NULL;
}

void append(int data)
{
    root = appendage(root, data);
}

void remove(int data)
{
    deletion(root,data);
}

void inorder()
{
    inorder_display(root);
    std::cout<<"\n";
}

void preorder()
{
    preorder_display(root);
    std::cout<<"\n";
}

void postorder()
{
    postorder_display(root);
    std::cout<<"\n";
}

int last()
{
    return last_right_node(root)->data;
}

~BinaryTree()
{
    destroy_tree(root);
}
};

 int main()
 {

BinaryTree b;
b.append(1);
b.append(2);
b.append(3);

b.append(4);
b.append(5);

b.inorder();
b.preorder();
b.postorder();

//std::cout<<b.last();

b.remove(2);

b.inorder();

return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please explain in detail your thinking behind each line of code within the suspected part. It is called "rubber ducking" and extremely useful.

Comment: You're copying the value from the leaf, then you delete the leaf without removing it from the tree. This leaves a dangling pointer in the tree. (As in the other cases, you should do this by only manipulating pointers.)

Comment: Moreover, your last right child can have left children and you are still deleting it.

Comment: Are you allowed to compile with [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) invoked as `g++ -Wall -Wextra -g` and to use the [GDB](https://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/) debugger?

Comment: Yes, when compile with GCC it worked but results in run time error as the value were swapped but the node wasn't deleted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've changed the last right node function where it returns parent of leaf node.
I've linked children of targeted node with last right node (leaf node) and then after removing it from it's parent node I swap it with the targeted node!
It works fine with all the cases!

```
        /*
        Depth First Traversals: 
        (a) Inorder (Left, Root, Right) : 4 2 5 1 3 
        (b) Preorder (Root, Left, Right) : 1 2 4 5 3 
        (c) Postorder (Left, Right, Root) : 4 5 2 3 1
        */

        #include <iostream>

        class BinaryTree
        {
            struct Node
            {
                int data;
                Node *left_child;
                Node *right_child;
            };

            Node *root;
            //////// *** CHANGES BELOW HERE *** 
            Node *last_right_node(Node *root)
            {
                Node *parent_node = root;

                if ((root->right_child)->right_child == NULL)
                {
                    return parent_node;
                }        

                return last_right_node(root->right_child);
            }
            //////// *** CHANGES ABOVE HERE *** 

            Node *appendage(Node *root, int data)
            {
                if (root == NULL)
                {
                    root = new Node();
                    root->data = data;
                    root->left_child = NULL;
                    root->right_child = NULL;
                    return root;
                }

                else if (root->left_child == NULL and root->right_child == NULL)
                {
                    root->left_child = appendage(root->left_child, data);
                }

                else if (root->left_child != NULL and root->right_child == NULL)
                {
                    root->right_child = appendage(root->right_child, data);
                }

                else
                {
                    root->left_child = appendage(root->left_child, data);
                }

                return root;
            }

            Node *deletion(Node *root, int data)
            {
                if (root == NULL)
                {
                    return root;
                }

                else if (data != root->data)
                {
                    root->left_child = deletion(root->left_child, data);
                    root->right_child = deletion(root->right_child, data);
                }

                else
                {
                    if (root->left_child == NULL && root->right_child == NULL)
                    {
                        delete root;
                        return NULL;
                    }

                    else if (root->left_child == NULL)
                    {
                        Node *temp_node = root;
                        root = root->right_child;
                        delete temp_node;
                    }

                    else if (root->right_child == NULL)
                    {
                        Node *temp_node = root;
                        root = root->left_child;
                        delete temp_node;
                    }
                    //////// *** SOLVED BELOW *** 
                    else
                    {
                        // PARENT NODE OF LEAF NODE
                        Node *temp_node = last_right_node(root);
                        // LEAF NODE
                        Node *leaf_node = temp_node->right_child;
                        // REMOVING LEAF NODE FROM TREE
                        temp_node->right_child = NULL;
                        // LINKING LEAF NODE WITH TARGET NODE CHILDREN
                        leaf_node->left_child = root->left_child;
                        leaf_node->right_child = root->right_child;
                        // SWAPPING THE NODE
                        root = leaf_node;
                    }
                    //////// *** SOLVED ABOVE *** 
                }        
            
                return root;
            }
            
            void inorder_display(Node *root)
            {
                if (root == NULL)
                {
                    return;
                }
                inorder_display(root->left_child);
                std::cout<<root->data<<" ";
                inorder_display(root->right_child);
            }

            void preorder_display(Node *root)
            {
                if (root == NULL)
                {
                    return;
                }
                std::cout<<root->data<<" ";
                preorder_display(root->left_child);
                preorder_display(root->right_child);
            }

            void postorder_display(Node *root)
            {
                if (root == NULL)
                {
                    return;
                }
                postorder_display(root->left_child);
                postorder_display(root->right_child);
                std::cout<<root->data<<" ";
            }

            Node *destroy_tree(Node *root)
            {
                if (root != NULL)
                {
                    destroy_tree(root->left_child);
                    destroy_tree(root->right_child);
                    delete root;
                }
                return root;
            }


            public:

            BinaryTree()
            {
                root = NULL;
            }

            void append(int data)
            {
                root = appendage(root, data);
            }

            void remove(int data)
            {
                root = deletion(root,data);
            }

            void inorder()
            {
                inorder_display(root);
                std::cout<<"\n";
            }

            void preorder()
            {
                preorder_display(root);
                std::cout<<"\n";
            }

            void postorder()
            {
                postorder_display(root);
                std::cout<<"\n";
            }

            ~BinaryTree()
            {
                destroy_tree(root);
            }
        };

        int main()
        {
            BinaryTree b;
            b.append(1);
            b.append(2);
            b.append(3);
            
            b.append(4);
            b.append(5);
            
            b.inorder();
            b.preorder();
            b.postorder();

            b.remove(1);

            b.inorder();

            return 0;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to post a section in Java, but I assume if you're doing BinaryTrees you can read it haha. Anyways, it looks like you have `Node` defined which is equivilent to my `BinaryTreeNode<T>` and then you want to have a constructor that takes in a left and right tree node to recursively define the tree.

```
protected BinaryTreeNode<T> _root = null ;

public LinkedBinaryTree() {}

public LinkedBinaryTree( T element )
{
    _root = new BinaryTreeNode<T>( element ) ; 
}

public LinkedBinaryTree( T element, 
        LinkedBinaryTree<T> left, LinkedBinaryTree<T> right )
{
    _root = new BinaryTreeNode<T>( element ) ;
    _root.setLeft( left.getRootNode() ) ;
    _root.setRight( right.getRootNode() );
}

public BinaryTreeNode<T> getRootNode() { return _root ; }
```

That might help with redifining your structure.

I'll show my entire remove sections with a few comments. I think you might want to focus on the "//has 2 children" else clause and see what's happening; I'm too tired to compare ours (This is my binarySEARCHtree version)

```
public T removeElement(T target)
        throws ElementNotFoundException
{
    if( isEmpty() )
        throw new ElementNotFoundException() ;
    
    T result = null ;
    
    if( target.equals( _root.getElement() ) )
    {
        result = _root.getElement() ;
        BinaryTreeNode<T> temp = replacement( _root ) ; 
        
        if( temp == null )
            _root = null ;
        else
        {
            _root.setElement( temp.getElement() );
            _root.setLeft( temp.getLeft() ) ;
            _root.setRight( temp.getRight() ) ;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        BinaryTreeNode<T> parent = _root ;
        if( target.compareTo( _root.getElement() ) < 0 )
            result = removeElement( target, _root.getLeft(), parent ) ;
        else
            result = removeElement( target, _root.getRight(), parent ) ;
    }
    
    return result ;
}

/** @child of @removeElement( T target ) */
private T removeElement( T target, BinaryTreeNode<T> node, BinaryTreeNode<T> parent )
{
    if( node == null )
        throw new ElementNotFoundException() ;
    
    T result = null ; 
    
    if( target.equals( node.getElement() ) )
    {
        result = node.getElement() ;
        BinaryTreeNode<T> temp = replacement( node ) ; 
        
        if( parent.getRight() == node )
            parent.setRight(temp) ;
        else
            parent.setLeft( temp ) ;
    }
    else
    {
        parent = node ;
        if( target.compareTo(node.getElement()) < 0 )
            result = removeElement( target, node.getLeft(), parent ) ;
        else
            result = removeElement( target, node.getRight(), parent ) ;
    }
    
    return result ;
}

/** @child of @removeElement */
private BinaryTreeNode<T> replacement( BinaryTreeNode<T> node )
{
    BinaryTreeNode<T> result = null ;
    
    if( ( node.getLeft() == null ) && ( node.getRight() == null ) )
    {
        result = null ;
    }
    else if( ( node.getLeft() != null ) && ( node.getRight() == null )  )
    {
        result = node.getLeft() ;
    }
    else if( ( node.getLeft() == null ) && ( node.getRight() != null )  )
    {
        result = node.getRight() ;
    }
    else
    { //has 2 children
        BinaryTreeNode<T> parent = node ;
        BinaryTreeNode<T> current = node.getRight() ;
        
        while( current.getLeft() != null )
        {
            parent  = current ;
            current = parent.getLeft() ;
        }
        
        current.setLeft( node.getLeft() ) ;
        if( node.getRight() != current )
        {
            parent.setLeft(current.getRight() ) ;
            current.setRight( node.getRight() ) ;
        }
        
        result = current ;
    }

    return result ;
}
```

Comment: I think you need to provide more explanation to make other users consider your java solution helpful to this C++ question.